# Meteor delete operation does not work with Mongo retryWrites flag

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I've realised that when I attempt to delete a document if the `retryWrites` flag is set to on `retryWrites=true` on my `mongo uri`, the collection `delete` operation does not work.

Here is the error:

> MongoError: Cannot use (or request) retryable writes with limit=0

Is there any way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just solve my problem using "rawCollection" like this:

```
myCollection.rawCollection().findOneAndDelete({_id: myId})
```

more info about meteor rawCollection is [here](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-rawCollection)

I hope that could help